# How does a JMS consumer work on a broker CLUSTER of Oracle Message Queue?

Tags: oracle, cluster-computing, glassfish-3, messaging

We have an application running in a GlassFish 3.1.2.2 cluster (two instances) that writes its results to "the_output_queue".

GlassFish sets up Message Queue as an embedded broker cluster, which in turn has also two message broker instances corresponding directly to the two GlassFish instances.

Now I would like to consume results from the_output_queue with an *external* JMS client (think Android app).

I assumed that a broker cluster can somehow be accessed transparently by a JMS client, but I cannot get this to work. I only succeed in connecting a JMS client to one individual broker.

If I have *one* JMS client running, connected to one broker I get only half of the messages. The physical queue (the_output_queue) defined in the GlassFish Administration Console exists in both brokers and the messages get evenly distributed thanks to load balancing.

[This text from the Oracle manuals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24949/broker-clusters.htm#ggssc) sounds to me like every message should be available in *all* broker instances of the cluster, i.e. if only a single JMS consumer is running it should receive all messages irrespective of the broker instance it is connected to.

*"The home broker is responsible for routing and delivering the messages to all consumers of the destination, whether these consumers are local (connected to the home broker) or remote (connected to other brokers in the cluster)."*

Have I misunderstood this completely?

**Can a JMS client access a  Oracle Message Queue broker cluster transparently?**
How would the connection string look?

Is there some "global cluster target" (instead of an individual broker) to which the JMS client can connect? Where could I find the connection details for the cluster?

Is there something special in the GlassFish setup I have to verify? The settings currently are (default setup created by jelastic.com, looks good to me):

JMS Availability:

- JMS Service Type: Embedded
- JMS Cluster Type: Conventional
- JMS Configuration Store Type: Master Broker
- JMS Message Store Type: File

GMS is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the main question: **Yes, a JMS client can connect to any instance of a cluster and GlassFish will replicate the messages**. I have tested it on my PC.

The problem in Jelastic is discussed [in this posting](https://www.java.net///forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/writing-jms-client-message-queue-broker-cluster-embedded-glassfish-312).